# A problem on the string in SetOptions

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to change the background of the notebook automatically by

```
str = NotebookDirectory[] // ToString
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  BackgroundAppearance -> FrontEnd`FileName[{str}, "BackgroundPic.png"]]
```

But it reports an error: `An improper nine patch image input option was encountered.`

However, if I replace the `str` with a string, it works

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 BackgroundAppearance -> 
  FrontEnd`FileName[{"C:\\MyDocuments\\MathematicaDoc\\"}, 
   "BackgroundPic.png"]]
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the ```FrontEnd`FileName``` code intended to accomplish? The output of NotebookDirectory is already a string, so you do need `ToString`. There is also a missing opening quote in your code, in `BackgroundPic.png"`, but I assume that might be a copy / paste problem.

Comment: I think it is complete `FrontEnd``FileName[{str}, "BackgroundPic.png"]`, although I don't understand how this `FrontEnd``FileName` works, especially the ```` in the code . I used `ToString` was to make sure that it was not a problem of `str` not being a string.

Comment: ``FrontEnd`FileName`` is `HoldAll` and the FrontEnd will not go back to the kernel to resolve `str`.

Comment: @ihojnicki what does ` mean in the code? And I try `Evaluate[str]` and it does not work. How should I fix it?

Comment: The backtick is the context marker, it separates the context (aka namespace) from the symbol name.  As for how to "fix" it, you should read the ref page for `With`.

Comment: And for the record, you are probably better off just importing the image. `BackgroundAppearance -> 
 Import[FileNameJoin[{...,...}]`.

Comment: Hi, the problem is still there when I try `BackgroundAppearance ->   Import[FileNameJoin[{str,"BackgroundPic.png"}]`

Comment: I would double check what you entered.  It works fine for me in 12.3 on Windows. `str = NotebookDirectory[]; SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], BackgroundAppearance -> Import[FileNameJoin[{str, "test.png"}]]]`.

Comment: Thanks! It works!